# How do I exclude a package from an imported JAR for a project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, package

How do I exclude a package from an imported JAR for a project in Eclipse?

I managed to figure out how to exclude a default package from all the projects, but not just one alone from a imported JAR nor for a specific project. I didn't see anything that resembled what I needed from the filters.

Comment: Is that a maven project?

Comment: please be more specific

Comment: @AlexandreSantos It is not; it is a Java project.

Comment: @ScaryWombat What specific information do you need?

Comment: why do you need to exclude a package?  Do you have some conflict?

Comment: @ScaryWombat The JAR has two packages that are very similar and I don't want to accidentally choose the wrong one, so I want to exclude it to prevent that from happening. I have no use for the other package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right-click on your java project
2. Select Build Path->Configure build path, then Libraries tab
3. locate your referenced JAR, then expand its properties with the little triangular arrow on its left:[image]
4. Click on "Access rules", then on the "Edit ..." button on the right
5. In the "Type Access Rules" window, click "Add ..."
6. For "Resolution", select "Forbidden"
7. In the "Rule Pattern" field, type in your exclusion pattern. If you want to exclude the default package classes, and only those (that's how I read your question), then the pattern would simply be: [*]. For a full description of patterns, check out the [ANT page](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns) which this mechanism is based on.
8. Click OK on all open windows.

The classes you've excluded should now no longer be available in your project. I tested the steps above on Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: Of course this will work in Eclipse only, not in production environment: it is useful if you want to avoid to use inadvertently a class when writing code.  For a detailed explanation see http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53736.html

Comment: @NotSoOldNick I did "folder1.folder2.foler3.*", but I was still able to import it using intellisense.

Comment: @dalawh The syntax needs to be folder-like. In your case: folder1/folder2/folder3/* for all classes directly in that package, or folder1/folder2/folder3/** for any classes in that package or sub-packages (as just retested in Eclipse). Give it a try :)

Comment: @NotSoOldNick That worked. Took me a bit of time to realize that I could still import it, but it won't appear on IntelliSense.